# MDX query to have a snapshoot at a given date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have the following fact table :

```
Date       Item   Step Value
2015-01-01 1      1     1.00
2015-01-01 2      1     2.00
2015-01-01 1      2     3.00
2015-01-02 1      2     4.00
2015-01-03 2      3     8.00
2015-01-05 1      3    16.00
```

And I'm looking for a script to find the value of items in each step at a given date.

For example, for the date `'2015-01-04'`, the resultset would be :

```
Step Value
1    0.00
2    4.00
3    8.00
```

I'm on SQL Server 2008.

===== Update 1 to make the question more understandable

Items can change of step as we can see in the fact table, so item is in one and only one step at a time. So when we calculate the value of a step, we have to sum up the value of each item that are present in this step.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of step 1 be 3.00? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti : step 1 is 0.00 because items 1 and 2 have moved from step 1. So I going to check your answer and I will kieep you posted.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "because items 1 and 2 have moved from step 1"?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti : Of course. At the end of 2015-01-01, Items 1 is in the step 2 and item 2 in 1. One day later,  no one move so it's the same. The 2015-01-03, item 1 is in 3 and 2 is in 1. And so on.

Comment: @Polux2 please can you add in some details of the cube you are using - a screen print of the measures / dimensions / hierarchies that are in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in affirmative to what I questioned in comment above, below might help you -

```
WITH MEMBER SumOfValueTillNow AS
SUM(null:[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].Value)

SELECT SumOfValueTillNow ON 0
FROM [YourCube]
WHERE ([Date].[Date].[2015-01-04])
```

Or, If you are looking for the `value` for each date, then the below -

```
SELECT SumOfValueTillNow ON 0,
[Date].[Date].CHILDREN ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the resultset is : `SumOfValueTillNow
#Error` for the two queries. I'm going to edit the question to clarify it. Thanks for your try.